# hyperref : how to color the whole "Figure 4" and not just the "4"?

Tags: floats, hyperref, captions, links

I have a simple question: how can I make `hyperref` link (and color) the whole "Figure X" or "Table X" instead of just the "X"?

I use it as :

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, linkcolor=blue,  citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,,pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,pdftitle={Your title here},
    pdfauthor={John Doe},
    pdfsubject={News},
    pdfkeywords={crazy stuff},
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true  ,pdfstartview=Fit      }

\usepackage{hypcap}
```

Comment: You can use `\autoref` instead of `\ref`. Also, since all your link colors are the same, you can set `allcolors=blue` instead of setting colors individually for `url`, `cite`, and `link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that @Kevinc gave is correct. It is the following:

> You can use `\autoref` instead of `\ref`. Also, since all your link colors
>   are the same, you can set `allcolors=blue` instead of setting colors
>   individually for `url`, `cite`, and `link`

Comment: A slightly related read [Why people answer in comments](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments)